# How to Validate field dependent on selection from MultiSelectList

Tags: validation, multi-select

I am new to MVC and I am stuck on validation.  A field is required if the user selects other from the MultiSelectList. I have tried to put the validation inside the controller HttpPost ActionResult.  Although the validation goes through and gets the error, the view becomes blank and I am not sure how to resolve this.  I have read on creating validation attribute but cannot see how it would work.  Please help.

In my Model I ave a multiselectlist Listofformat and an array string to store selected values.
I have another field named OtherSFiormat which is mandatory if the selection string contains a "6" for "Other"

```
    [Display(Name = "Please state the other format of the system ")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public String OtherSFormat { get; set; } 

    public MultiSelectList ListofFormat { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedFormat { get; set; }
```

In my controller I tried to put this code and catch with 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult General(int id, GeneralViewModel vm)

```
 {
        // Do validation 
        // check other format is entered if other is selected.
        //if (vm.ListofFormat.SelectedValues == 6  )

 if (vm.SelectedFormat.ToList().Contains("6") && (String.IsNullOrEmpty       (vm.OtherSFormat))) 
 {
    modelErrors.Add("Please provide details of other system format");
 }
        //check if superceded has some value

 if (vm.SystemStatus == "Superseded" && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SupersededBy)))
 {
   ModelState.AddModelError("SupersededBy", "Please state which system it has superceded by");
 }
   if (modelErrors.Count > 0)
 {
    throw new DbEntityValidationException("");
 }


 }
      catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
 {
      foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
 {
     foreach (var modelError in modelState.Errors)
 {
      modelErrors.Add(modelError.ErrorMessage);
 }
 }
                    // do something with the error list
  TempData["tErrorList"] = modelErrors;
```

and then tried to return view, model and return View() but everything fails with errors.  If I redirect to the General Action it brings up the errorlist but blank view.
I also tried to add to ModelState, but that does not show the error as you can see from the field used for Superceded .  I have only partially posted the code so there may be missing }
Any help will be most appreciated.